# Using append returns [object]?

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have a bit of code that concatenates text from some input boxes and the resulting string is then put into a `<span>`. I've got a '+' button which copies the `<span>` and appends it to the end of a `<div>`.

Now I want to add a `<br>` at the end of the `<span>` so that each span is placed on a new line but when I do this pressing the "+" returns `[object][Object]` as opposed to the values! I've setup a js fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aexK8/2/).

You will see what I mean when you click '+'. It's probably something very simple but I can't for the life of me find out what is causing this!

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because using the + operator with a string coerces everything to string, resulting in the string representation of the jQuery object (which is usually `[Object object]`). Try:

```
$("#five").append(creativeCopy.html() + "<br>");
```

or:

```
$("#five").append(creativeCopy).append("<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var creativeUniqueId = 1;
    $(".addCreative").click(function() {
        var creativeCopy = $("#creative_text").clone();
        var creativeCopyId = "creative_text" +creativeUniqueId;
        creativeCopy.attr("id",creativeCopyId);
        $("#five").append(creativeCopy);
         $("#five").append("<br>");
        creativeUniqueId++;
    }); 
});
```

You can see at http://jsfiddle.net/aexK8/3/